# Google Universal Analytics tracking code generating an empty page

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, smarty, universal-analytics

It is the first time i am using the new version of Google Analytics (Universal Analytics), so when i put the below code imediatally before `</head>` i get blank pages for all my URLs.

Here is the code given by Google:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-1234567-89', 'mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Someone knows why it is happening? Seems to be a bug, but i don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Try debugging in your browser's dev tools. I would open the Chrome "Network" panel to see if there are any redirects taking place, or any JS / HTML loaded that is breaking the site. Use the "Preserve Log upon Navigation" option to make sure you don't miss anything. Also look for JS errors in the Console.

Comment: @providencemac, The page is comming totally empty. If i remove the tracking code it works normally. This is very strange

Comment: Can you share you site with Universal Analytics in it (the empty page)? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you removed 'mysite.com' from this code and your Google Analytics settings?

Comment: @Blexy, I updated the question, now it has the original UA and website. The URL is [adconsultoriaeprojetos.com](http://adconsultoriaeprojetos.com). If you find anything, please tell me

Comment: @MarcioSimao This problem is server-side, if there is no data being sent to the client as you claim.  Sounds like you have a template engine that doesn't like JavaScript.

Comment: @Brad, I didn't remove it, it is exactly like this `ga('create', 'UA-4155959-21', 'adconsultoriaeprojetos.com');`

Comment: @Brad, Good pointing. I am using Smarty (PHP Engine Template), maybe it has some problem with Universal Analytics. Please post your comment as an answer, probably will be the best one.

Comment: @MarcioSimao Ha, I wondered.  I also use Smarty and have had this exact same problem before. `{literal}` tags are what you need, since Smarty uses brackets by default for its delimeters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @Brad comment i detected that PHP Smarty was crashing with Universal Analytics code tracking, so i found this post:

[Use {Literal} Smarty Tag to Add Google Analytics Tracking Code to BlogSome Hosted Blogs](http://www.mydigitallife.info/use-literal-smarty-tag-to-add-google-analytics-tracking-code-to-blogsome-hosted-blogs/)

And then i did like below and the tracking code works perfectly!

```
<script>

    {literal}

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-1234567-89', 'mysite.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    {/literal}

</script>
```